# Set activity to be started anytime user opens application

Tags: android, android-activity

Is there a way to set which activity is to be started anytime the application is opened? Obviously I have the Intent Filters android.intent.action.MAIN and android.intent.category.LAUNCHER, but I want it to reset to this activity even if the App wasn't completely killed (if it wasn't, now it just goes back to the last activity that was open)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to go straight to your initial activity every time you start the app from the launcher? Set  android:clearTaskOnLaunch to true in your Activity tags in the manifest.

from the docs

```
Whether or not all activities will be removed from the task, except for the root activity,     
whenever it is re-launched from the home screen — "true" if the task is always stripped 
down to its root activity, and "false" if not. The default value is "false". This 
attribute is meaningful only for activities that start a new task (the root activity);
it's ignored for all other activities in the task.
```

Answer (score 0):

When switching between Intents you can call finish() to kill the previous activity. Ideally you could probably go from this first activity, to the first activity again, killing it in the process.

In the main java file you can put the following in your onClick or whatever. And you can do the same in reverse within the second activity to switch back to the main, each time refreshing the activity.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class); 
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: I tried this, but my app requires being able to use the back button to previous activities, and when I called finish() the back button was useless

Comment: You could set a variable to track the intent you're coming from and have your application handle the back key. By implementing the OnKeyListener:
`code`    boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
   //your action
  else if(event.getAction () == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)
                        //do nothing

Comment: Ah that's true. The other answer works well, but I may end up doing this too